# Add new column based on existing column with concat values Spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I want to new column in my dataframe based on below condition.

My dataframe is like this:

```
my_string 

2020 test 

2020 prod 

2020 dev
```

My condition:

```
value1=subtract string after space from my_string

value2=subtract first four digit from my_string

If value 1 contains string 'test' then new_col=value2+"01"

If value 1 contains string 'prod' then new_col=value2+"kk"

If value 1 contains string 'dev' then new_col=value2+"ff"
```

I need result like this:

> ```
> my_string       |  new_col
>
> 2020 test        | 202001
>
> 2020 prod        | 2020kk 
>
> 2020 dev        | 2020ff
> ```

Please can someone help me out?

Comment: can you please format your input & expected output something like tabular format ? so that it is readable & anyone can you give easy solution .. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`row_number`** window function with **`monotonically_increasing_id()`**

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
w = Window.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id())
df.withColumn("new_col",concat(split(col("my_string")," ")[0], lpad(row_number().over(w),2,"0"))).show()

#+---------+-------+
#|my_string|new_col|
#+---------+-------+
#|2020 test| 202001|
#|2020 prod| 202002|
#| 2020 dev| 202003|
#+---------+-------+
```

---

**`UPDATE:`**

Use **`when+otherwise`** statement.

```
df.withColumn("dyn_col",when(lower(split(col("my_string")," ")[1]) =="prod","kk").\
when(lower(split(col("my_string")," ")[1]) =="dev","ff").\
when(lower(split(col("my_string")," ")[1]) =="test","01").\
otherwise("null")).\
withColumn("new_col",concat(split(col("my_string")," ")[0], col("dyn_col"))).\
drop("dyn_col").\
show()
#+---------+-------+
#|my_string|new_col|
#+---------+-------+
#|2020 test| 202001|
#|2020 prod| 2020kk|
#| 2020 dev| 2020ff|
#+---------+-------+
```

**`In Scala:`**

```
df.withColumn("dyn_col",when(lower(split(col("my_string")," ")(1)) ==="prod","kk").
when(lower(split(col("my_string")," ")(1)) ==="dev","ff").
when(lower(split(col("my_string")," ")(1)) ==="test","01").
otherwise("null")).
withColumn("new_col",concat(split(col("my_string")," ")(0), col("dyn_col"))).
drop("dyn_col").
show()

//+---------+-------+
//|my_string|new_col|
//+---------+-------+
//|2020 test| 202001|
//|2020 prod| 2020kk|
//| 2020 dev| 2020ff|
//+---------+-------+
```

Comment: it's not row_number i just gave sample it may vary like any string edited again

Comment: Thanks you so much i will try